# Pass a Parameter to DAX Query Report Builder

Tags: parameter-passing, dax

I need some help here.  Below is a DAX query that I have copied over from Power BI into Power BI Report Builder. I'm looking to pass a parameter into this query for 'edw dim_paycom_amcs_location_xref'[Paycom_Location_Desc].  However, I'm not sure where to place it within the query. I've researched the heck out of this and no matter where I try to place it I receive errors. Can anyone help with this?  Thank you very much.

```
      // DAX Query
DEFINE
  VAR __DS0FilterTable = 
    TREATAS({"2021"}, 'edw dimDate'[Year])

  VAR __DS0FilterTable2 = 
    TREATAS({"August"}, 'edw dimDate'[MonthName])

  VAR __DS0Core = 
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
      'edw dimDate'[MonthYear],
      'edw dimDate'[Month],
      'edw dim_paycom_amcs_location_xref'[Paycom_Location_Desc],
      __DS0FilterTable,
      __DS0FilterTable2,
      "SumOvertime_Hours_by_Day", CALCULATE(SUM('PaycomHours'[Overtime_Hours_by_Day])),
      "SumReg_Hours_by_Day", CALCULATE(SUM('PaycomHours'[Reg_Hours_by_Day])),
      "Transportation", 'PaycomHours'[Transportation],
      "Total_Inbound_Tons", 'PaycomHours'[Total Inbound Tons],
      "Total_Inbound_Tons__excl_Yakima_", 'PaycomHours'[Total Inbound Tons (excl Yakima)],
      "No_Operating_Days", 'edw dimDate'[No.Operating Days],
      "Tonnage_Inbound__3rd_Party", 'PaycomHours'[Tonnage Inbound- 3rd Party],
      "Tonnage_Inbound__Intercompany", 'PaycomHours'[Tonnage Inbound- Intercompany],
      "Tonnage_Inbound___3rd_Party_Metal", 'PaycomHours'[Tonnage Inbound - 3rd Party Metal],
      "Tonnage___Intercompany_Metal", 'PaycomHours'[Tonnage - Intercompany Metal],
      "Tonnage___Intercompany_Hog_Fuel", 'PaycomHours'[Tonnage - Intercompany Hog Fuel],
      "Tonnage___3rd_Party_Hog_Fuel", 'PaycomHours'[Tonnage - 3rd Party Hog Fuel],
      "Total_Commodities_Volume_Sold", 'PaycomHours'[Total Commodities Volume Sold],
      "Tonnage___Intercompany_Cardboard", 'PaycomHours'[Tonnage - Intercompany Cardboard],
      "Tonnage___Intercompany_ALL", 'PaycomHours'[Tonnage - Intercompany ALL],
      "Tonnage___3rd_Party_ALL", 'PaycomHours'[Tonnage - 3rd Party ALL]
    )

  VAR __DS0PrimaryWindowed = 
    TOPN(
      501,
      __DS0Core,
      'edw dimDate'[Month],
      1,
      'edw dimDate'[MonthYear],
      1,
      'edw dim_paycom_amcs_location_xref'[Paycom_Location_Desc],
      1
    )

EVALUATE
  __DS0PrimaryWindowed

ORDER BY
  'edw dimDate'[Month],
  'edw dimDate'[MonthYear],
  'edw dim_paycom_amcs_location_xref'[Paycom_Location_Desc]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the following:

```
DEFINE
    VAR __DS0FilterTable =
        TREATAS ( { "2021" }, 'edw dimDate'[Year] )
    VAR __DS0FilterTable2 =
        TREATAS ( { "August" }, 'edw dimDate'[MonthName] )
    VAR __DS0FilterTable3 =
        TREATAS ( { @Location }, 'edw dim_paycom_amcs_location_xref'[Paycom_Location_Desc] )
    VAR __DS0Core =
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
            'edw dimDate'[MonthYear],
            'edw dimDate'[Month],
            'edw dim_paycom_amcs_location_xref'[Paycom_Location_Desc],
            __DS0FilterTable,
            __DS0FilterTable2,
            __DS0FilterTable3,
            [... Remainder of query the same ...]
```

Be sure to map `@Location` to your report parameter here:

[image: Dataset Properties screenshot]

Comment: Hi Alexis, thank you very much.  Even after mapping the parameter I'm receiving an error that says "The query contains the 'Location' parameter which is not declared. Any idea? Thanks again.

Comment: I fixed this error by adding the parameter in the Query Designer.  Now when I try to run it I receive the following error.  The expression used for the parameter 'Location' in the dataset 'Location' refers to a field.  Fields cannot be used in query parameter expressions.
----------------------------
The definition of the report '' is invalid.
----------------------------
An error occurred during local report processing

Comment: Seems like you've set up your parameter strangely but it's hard to tell without looking at the file.

Comment: My similar issue was getting parameter error 'the query contains the parameter which is not declared' but the kicker is the error was pertaining to the query designer version.  Married up the querys to be the same, fixed the associated parameters then back in business.    The query designer is literally bug and needs to be removed.  Build querys externally then add to query properties and build manually within report builder for full control.

Answer (score 2):

I've struggled a lot with parameters with DAX in Report Builder.  There are a few different approaches depending on what your needs are.

The first question, do you need users to be able to change the value of the parameter?  If so, you will need to define it under "Parameters" in Report Data.

Next regardless of your previous answer, you need to define the parameter in your dataset. [image: Screenshot of Dataset Properties Window showing a parameter named MonthDS mapped to a value of [@Month] and a parameter named CustomerDS mapped to a value of [@Customer].]
If you are using a user-selectable parameter, then use the notation shown in the screenshot of [@User_Parameter_Name].  If you click into the function editor, you will see this corresponds to the VB.Net expression `=Parameters!User_Parameter_Name.Value`

The second question is if you are entering the query directly into the Query box in the Dataset Properties.  If you are just pasting your DAX from PBI into that box, then you should be good to go.

However, if you are using the Query Designer (and I can't blame you if you don't), then you need to do as you have already discovered and re-declare the parameter within the Query Designer.
[image: Screenshot of Query Designer Query Parameters window with a parameter declared named MonthQP]
The problem with the Query Parameters here is that they really struggle with defaulting to empty values... Also, when I have a parameter, Query Designer always seems to forget that I'm using DAX and not MDX every time I opened it.

But anyways, once you declare it here, then you can refer to them in the query itself.

Finally, if you need to pass a list of values instead of a single value, the only way I've gotten this to work is to use this strange, little-documented function RSCustomDaxFilter to create a filter table:

```
 VAR MonthFilter= 
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
        'Month'[Month],
        RSCustomDaxFilter(@MonthQP,EqualToCondition, [Month].[Month], String
        )
```

I can make some inferences on how this function works; the Table.Field syntax and specifying the object type make me think at least modeled after VB.Net, but aside from examples of how to use it in pretty much only this exact scenario, I have yet to find any official documentation on how it works, and the best explanation is from [Chris Webb's blog, back in 2019](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2019/11/03/power-bi-report-builder-and-rscustomdaxfilter/).  Also, it loves to freeze when performing query preparation if you don't use the Query Designer!

Answer (score 1):

DAX pattern schematic that I use.  No need to use RSCustomDaxFilter function and thus you can use DaxStudio to work on your querys.  Hallelujah :}

```
/*  
History
    yyyymmdd  aa  build

Datasets
    abbrev = workspace.dataset.table

Notes    
    + etc
*/

EVALUATE

-- parse the parameter value lists ready for the main querys
VAR ParameterA = SUBSTITUTE (TRIM (SUBSTITUTE (@ParameterA, ",", "|")), "| ", "|" )


-- build the lists
VAR TableA =
    FILTER (
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            'table',
            "column a", 'table '[column a],
            "column b", 'table '[column b],
            etc
        ),

        -- column a,  ParameterA
        SWITCH (
            TRUE (),
            LEN (ParameterA) = 0,             TRUE (),   -- ignore
            PATHCONTAINS (ParameterA, "All"), TRUE (),   -- ignore   

            IF ( PATHCONTAINS ( ParameterA, "NA" ),   -- NA parameter selection
                IF ( [column a] IN 
                         {"NA",
                          "0",
                          "Not Applicable",
                          "Select",
                          " ", 
                          "",  
                          BLANK()}, 
                     TRUE (),   -- NA value found
                     IF ( PATHCONTAINS ( ParameterA, [column a] ), 
                          TRUE (),   -- direct match found
                          FALSE ()   -- out of scope condition
                     ) 
                ),
                FALSE ()   
            ),
            TRUE (),

            PATHCONTAINS ( ParameterA, [column a] ), TRUE (),
            FALSE ()   
        )  && 

    etc
    )

VAR TableB =
    etc


-- join the lists
VAR Result =
    NATURALINNERJOIN (TableA, TableB)

RETURN 
    Result
    --ROW ( "ParameterA", """"& ParameterA &"""" )   -- parameter checker  

ORDER BY   
    [column a] ASC,
    [column b] ASC


/* testing framework daxstudio */
<Parameters etc
  <Parameter>
    <Name></Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string"></Value>   
  </Parameter>
etc
</Parameters>
```